# From MathWorks assignDetectionsToTracks() to a similar function in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I've found in MathWorks the argument "Motion-Based Multiple Object Tracking" and in particular the functions like

```
assignDetectionsToTracks()
predictNewLocationsOfTracks()
```

and so on.

Is there something similar in C++ ?

More clearly: i must realize an object  tracking project in C++ and I've found in Mathworks the business logic that i must implement in my C++ project (without using the OpenCV API).

I'm trying  to convert this MathWorks business logic into C++ for to see if it can working well also in my project, but i have difficult to reorganize the MathWorks data structure ( [assignments,unassignedTracks,unassignedDetections] ) int o C++ data structures.

Is there someone that has already try to do this ?

Thanks
Danilo

Comment: read opencv source code first

Comment: ok I will follow your advice. Can you address me in some directions because unfortunately I can not use OPENCV api in developing, so I have to "rewrite" all in native C ++, but if there is some place where to find documentation .. you are welcome !!